# onLocationChanged not being called within the IndoorAtlas location manager

Tags: java, android, geolocation, on-location-changed

When testing I am able to receive updates from the onStatusChanged within the IALocationListener, but the onLocationChanged is not being called. Any ideas as to why this is?

I have followed the instructions from IndoorAtlas (http://docs.indooratlas.com/android/dev-guide/getting-user-location.html) as well as a video from YouTube (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2EXkV4xL5rg) but was still not able to get the location.

Do I have to be in the area that I have mapped or should it read the location no matter where I am?

```
package com.bignerdranch.android.indoormapping;

import android.Manifest;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocation;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocationListener;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocationManager;
import com.indooratlas.android.sdk.IALocationRequest;

public class MappingActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private final int CODE_PERMISSIONS = 0;
    private IALocationManager mIALocationManager;
    private static final String TAG = "LocateActivity";

    private IALocationListener mIALocationListener = new IALocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(IALocation iaLocation) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Latitude: " + iaLocation.getLatitude());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

        }
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mapping);

        mIALocationManager = IALocationManager.create(this);



        // request permissions for coarse location and Wifi
        String[] neededPermissions = {
                Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
        };
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions( this, neededPermissions, CODE_PERMISSIONS );

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_cont);

        if(fragment == null) {
            fragment = new MappingFragment();
            fm.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_cont, fragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }

    // handle any permissions that are denied
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions, int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mIALocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(IALocationRequest.create(), mIALocationListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mIALocationManager.removeLocationUpdates(mIALocationListener);
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Do I have to be in the area that I have mapped or should it read the location no matter where I am?"_ My (vague) understanding of IndoorAtlas' technology is that it only works in areas that are already mapped. It can't possibly work "everywhere" as it's based on the "magnetic fingerprint" of the building and that needs to be acquired first.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/IndoorAtlas/android-sdk-examples) IndoorAtlas has given some code examples of their SDK. You should be able to find the issue.